# divs display none ie6 and jquery toggle

Tags: jquery

I am currently using display none for the divs which I would like to use jquery toggle on. As usual something in ie6 is not the same compared to other browsers. First of all display none is adding white space and secondly its doing something weird. Imagine there is a word called elephant in div 1 and there is nothing in div 2 it is displaying the last few letters of elephant in div 2 for instance phant! When I removed display none every thing went fine is there any way around this so every thing is consistent in all browsers and I can keep using toggle. May I add it is working with a few other divs 99% consistently just a slight layout jerk in ie6. What might the problem be?

Comment: Html, Css and jquery code please..

Answer (score 0):

Try hidding the element with jquery instead of css:

```
$('element').hide();
```

If that doesn't work try like this:

```
$('element').css({'position': 'absolute', 'visibility': 'hidden'});
```